# Salesforce authentication using Rest API with JAVA

Tags: rest, salesforce, java, salesforce-service-cloud

I want to authenticate Salesforce using Salesforce Rest API with JAVA.

For this I follow the below URL

http://www.asagarwal.com/2401/step-by-step-guide-to-get-started-with-salesforce-rest-api-using-java

My java code is below

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;
import org.json.JSONException;

public class OrderProcessing extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    static final String PASS = "XXXXXXX";
    static final String SecurityToken = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
    static final String USERNAME = "adminuser@.salesforce.com";
    static final String PASSWORD = PASS + SecurityToken;
    static final String LOGINURL = "https://login.salesforce.com";
    static final String GRANTSERVICE = "/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=password";
    static final String CLIENTID = "ConsumerKeyFromSalesfoceConnectedApps";
    static final String CLIENTSECRET = "ConsumerSecretFromSalesforceConnectedApps";

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        String loginURL = LOGINURL + GRANTSERVICE + "&amp;client_id=" + CLIENTID + "&amp;client_secret=" + CLIENTSECRET
                + "&amp;username=" + USERNAME + "&amp;password=" + PASSWORD;

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(loginURL);
        HttpResponse resp = null;

        try {
            resp = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException cpException) {
            cpException.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }

        final int statusCode = resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            System.out.println("Error authenticating to Force.com: " + statusCode);
            return;
        }

        String getResult = null;
        try {
            getResult = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }

        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        String loginAccessToken = null;
        String loginInstanceUrl = null;
        try {
            jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(getResult).nextValue();
            loginAccessToken = jsonObject.getString("access_token");
            loginInstanceUrl = jsonObject.getString("instance_url");
        } catch (JSONException jsonException) {
            jsonException.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(resp.getStatusLine());
        System.out.println("Successful login");
        System.out.println("  instance URL: " + loginInstanceUrl);
        System.out.println("  access token/session ID: " + loginAccessToken);

        httpPost.releaseConnection();
    }
}
```

Response : `HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [Date: Thu, 06 Oct 2016 11:25:26 GMT, Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=10886400; includeSubDomains; preload, Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: default-src https:; script-src https: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src https: 'unsafe-inline'; img-src https: data:; font-src https: data:; report-uri /_/ContentDomainCSPNoAuth?type=login, Set-Cookie: BrowserId=bIo6TZOBQRSS2KFKtUR5ZA;Path=/;Domain=.salesforce.com;Expires=Mon, 05-Dec-2016 11:25:26 GMT, Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT, Pragma: no-cache, Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, X-ReadOnlyMode: false, Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8, Transfer-Encoding: chunked] ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8,Chunked: true]}}`

Response using Rest Web Service Client extension of Chrome : `{"error":"invalid_client_id","error_description":"client identifier invalid"}`

Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved my Issue using below code :

```
String loginURL = LOGINURL + GRANTSERVICE + "&client_id=" + CLIENTID + "&client_secret=" + CLIENTSECRET + "&username=" + USERNAME + "&password=" + PASSWORD;
```

in place of

```
String loginURL = LOGINURL + GRANTSERVICE + "&amp;client_id=" + CLIENTID + "&amp;client_secret=" + CLIENTSECRET
                + "&amp;username=" + USERNAME + "&amp;password=" + PASSWORD;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did it work before? If it was then you need auth again.

Answer (score 0):

It takes about 15 minutes for a new Connected App to be all setup.  Since the error indicates that the Client ID is bad, I'd guess that is what the issue is.  Can you try again?

Comment: I resolved this issue using String loginURL = LOGINURL + GRANTSERVICE + "&client_id=" + CLIENTID + "&client_secret=" + CLIENTSECRET + "&username=" + USERNAME + "&password=" + PASSWORD; But I want to create new user in Salesforce. So how can i do this? Please help me.